# LNK2001 error when trying to build a flutter application for windows

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication, firebase-storage, flutter-windows

Recently the firebase official packages including (Firebase_Auth, cloud_Firestore, and Firebase_storage), started supporting windows platform. Prior to that I was using community packages for the connection with firebase services but since the support was finally here I decided to switch my windows app to start using the official packages and here started the issue. Whenevr I try to build a flutter for windows app that contains any one of the mentioned packages I would get a "LNK2001" error.

> : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__CrtDbgReport
>
> error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__calloc_dbg
>
> error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__invalid_parameter

I have been searching all over the internet for a while and could not get my hand on a working solution.
I would highly appreciate any help in this matter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A bug was reported for this and fixed a couple of days ago.  See this link for more information.
https://github.com/firebase/flutterfire/pull/11997

If you update firebase_core to the latest version (I also updated firebase_auth and cloud_firestore as well in my app) this should resolve the issue

Comment: Thank you. I was following that report and updated my app as soon as they released the new version.